# Higher than 1920 x 1080 resolution with Intel 4000 graphics chipset

Tags: windows-7, resolution, integrated-graphics, 4k-resolution

Trying to hook up a Samsung U28D590 4K monitor (3840 x 2160 pixels) to a system with an integrated Intel 4000 graphics chipset (running Windows 7 SP1).

According to the Intel specs, the Intel 4000 chipset should be able to handle at least 2560 x 1600 resolution.

Windows is only allowing up to 1920 x 1080 pixels of resolution.

What has been tried:

- Installed the drivers that came with the monitor and rebooted, but no difference.
- Set the refresh rate of the monitor down to 30Hz, but no difference.
- Bought HDMI cables that specifically list support for 4K devices, but no difference.

Would like to get it to run at 2560 x 1600 (or higher).

How?

**Update:** Well, it looks like I've exhausted all possibilities, including trying 4K HDMI cables.  Taking a closer look at the specs for the Intel 4000 (which Intel has made amazingly difficult to find), it looks like it may only support resolutions above 1920x1080 when using DVI, which I don't have.  So the Samsung 4K display gets returned or sold.

Comment: You have the current driver release from Intel installed correct?  I had no problem using this resolution on my Surface Pro 3 to my 4k monitor.

Comment: what cable? If HDMI I'm guessing it's not HDMI 1.4 capable

Comment: @Tetsujin  HDMI.  When you say 'it's not' are you referring to the monitor or the system?  Besides looking at spec sheets (which seem to always be wrong), is there a way to tell if an HDMI port is 1.4 capable?

Comment: the port is likely to be capable - my guess was that the cable isn't. idk how you determine that, it might be stamped on the plug/cable

Comment: @Tetsujin The cable should be capable because it was included with the 4K monitor.

Comment: I tried 4 different cables from 3 different brands, yet nothing more than 1920x1080 resolution.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not 100% here, but I was looking into this recently and if my memory serves me right, it will display up to 2560x1600@60hz, and either UHD or 4K@30hz.

However I might be wrong, and it might be able to support a 4K display at 60hz if you run it with a display port cable.

Comment: Just to add: 1920×1080 is not the highest resolution in its class. **1920×1200 is.** So whenever you speak about the former (at certain frequency), the latter *always* works, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 2560×1600 on Intel HD 4000 without any tweaks:

[image]

There are some pitfalls like attempts to use HDMI display connection at standard HDMI 1.2 which cannot handle that resolution (you need HDMI 1.3, and above 2560×1600 you will need HDMI 1.4); or using cable with insufficient parameters for given link speed etc.

Add display type and HDMI level of your cables to the question to get more helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks, I added the display type to the question.  I'll try to find the box for the cables!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I'm not sure what is the culprit in your case. To be clear: in my case, Display is only HDMI 1.2 s I needed to use [USB to DisplayPort adapter](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-Displayport-Video-Card-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-2560x1600~USB32DPPRO). It is pretty slow but I work with text so it is bearable. Your display has HDMI 1.4 so there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.) right click on desktop, > Graphics Options > Custom Resolution 
2.) Select display(U28E570) Set Width 2560, Height 1600, Refresh Rate 24, Timing Standard = CVT-RB
3.) MUST Reboot !
4.) right click on desktop, > Display Settings, select 2nd monitor, go down to Display resolution select 2560 x 1600

Answer (score -1):

Intel HD Graphics 4000 can handle 4K @ 30p Hz with this steps and special Monitor

- Mac Mini Late 2012 with "Intel HD Graphics 4000"
- Boot Camp Installation of Windows 7
- Install Intel HD Graphics 4000 Drivers version 9.17.10.3347 (Legacy)
  find thisinside Boot Camp @ support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US
  Path: \BootCamp\Drivers\Intel\BootCamp5.1.5621.zip\BootCamp\Drivers\
- Samsung Monitor 4K U28E590 
  This the the trick! This monitor have Picture in Picture Option.
- From the windows Bar Open Intel Graphics Properties
- Advanced Mode
- Display --> Custom Resolutions
  Width=1920, Height=2160, Color Depth=All Colors, Refresh Rate=30,
  TimingStandard=CVT-RB ---> Add
- Restart your Computer.
- Connect both cables Mini-Port--> HDMI, and HDMI-->HDMI to this monitor
- On the monitor turn on Picture in picture and split in two the screen
- On Windows, right click on the Desktop --> Screen resolutions and arrange both displays like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMWJ.png)

Hope this helps

Now I need to figure it out how to do this on OS X El Capitan, cause I know tha is a fact that this Video Card is fully capable of 4K with this Monitor :)